# "key must be 16 bytes" AES-128 CBC, with MD5 Key+IV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, openssl, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm interacting with an API that requires me to encrypt something with `AES-128` in `CBC` mode.

They said for the key and the IV I need to use a 16-byte MD5 hash of a string they give me.

I've googled for awhile and it looks like all MD5 is 16 bytes, so why does this not work?

```
  key = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(temp_token)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(128, :CBC)
  cipher.encrypt
  cipher.key = key # ArgumentError: key must be 16 bytes
  cipher.iv = key # ArgumentError: iv must be 16 bytes

  encrypted = cipher.update(joined_params) + cipher.final
  Base64.urlsafe_encode64(encrypted)
```

Comment: If their external service implementations are this bad, imagine how badly their internal systems are implemented... *shudder*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the root cause is `OpenSSL::Cipher::AES#key` must take a 16 bytes string as its key.

```
[27] pry(main)> cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(128, :CBC)
=> #<OpenSSL::Cipher::AES:0x00007f7f876f1608>
[28] pry(main)> cipher.encrypt
=> #<OpenSSL::Cipher::AES:0x00007f7f876f1608>
[30] pry(main)> cipher.random_key.length
=> 16
```

It has nothing to do with `Digest::MD5.hexdigest`

```
[26] pry(main)> key = Digest::MD5.hexdigest('abc').first(16)
=> "900150983cd24fb0"
[27] pry(main)> cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(128, :CBC)
=> #<OpenSSL::Cipher::AES:0x00007f7f876f1608>
[28] pry(main)> cipher.encrypt
=> #<OpenSSL::Cipher::AES:0x00007f7f876f1608>
[29] pry(main)> cipher.key = key
=> "900150983cd24fb0"
```

Reference: [OpenSSL::Cipher](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I needed to use `Digest::MD5.digest` instead.

Comment: I'm glad it took you only 10 minutes to learn the difference between binary and hexadecimals, but I guess people will have to find out themselves, I see little point in this Q/A.

Comment: Well we all can't be Maarten Bodewes on stack overflow. Ya gotta start somewhere.

Comment: True and I was fortunate in the sense that I did have little choice to learn about it on my trusty MSX home computer. However, I'm afraid that the question won't be found. Beware that MD5 is not considered a good hashing algorithm anymore. The IV should be different if a key is reused, so you should not reuse the `temp_token`.

Comment: It's for a payment processing API that I have no control over. I'm stuck with all their outdated or bad security methodologies. I've already found a flaw in their gem where they're using the hexidigest method, and they're not reaizing it's getting truncated (which was fixed in a newer version to raise an error).